Module '"@angular/material"' has no exported member 'MatButtonModule'.ts
I have the below steps to install angular material in my angular project version 10.0.5.
After importing the MatButtonModule in app.module.ts file facing the below error.
Module '"@angular/material"' has no exported member 'MatButtonModule'.ts
Step1: npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk --force
step2: npm install --save @angular/animations --force
step3:
import {MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';
@NgModule({
  imports: [MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule]
})

After importing the MatButtonModule in app.module.ts file facing the below error.

Where did you get the import line from? I think that's wrong.

You have to import the individual modules by their individual paths
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';

@NgModule({
  imports: [MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule]
})

